# Integrating full calendar with Google calendar adding 'where' / 'location' field

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have integrated full calendar with my Google calendar, I have already disabled on click of each event, because I didn't want to share all the details of an event with others on my website. I just wanted to show when I am busy and when I am free.
The problem is that I even want to hide titles of events, and only display the 'location' or 'where' field of a google event. although the response I get includes the location, I don't know how should I get it and display it.
Here is my code:

```
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: {
        url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/a06g3aano640bal6idonn44ves%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        className: 'gcal-event',
        color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black'
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        if ( event.allDay) {
            element.css({'background-color': 'red',
                         'border':'1px solid red'});
        }
    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
            return false;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not complicated, just check if the location is set inside `eventRender`. If it is, show it as title, otherwise show the default text:

```
var title = ( event.location ) ? event.location : 'Doing something';
element.html(title);
```

Comment: You just solved my problem without even knowing about it. Thank you very much. [link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784629/how-to-check-for-empty-event-description-google-calendar-feed)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did it by changing the fullcalendar.js file, where it was set to "title" I changed it to event.location, and it did work :)
But now I have another problem, I am still looking into event object, but I cannot find it there. and that's I have to check busy/availability of an event to change the color of that event accordingly. But still didn\t figure it out yet.